# Is it possible to initialize a AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider with an existing AWSCognitoAuthUserSession?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

We have a react native app, and we're trying to use AWSS3TransferUtility from to upload a large file across a native bridge (ios/obj-c).

We authenticate in js, and somehow need to pass credentials across to obj-c into the AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider (so that we can refresh credentials if the long running upload takes a long time, exceeds expiration, etc).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the answer is mostly no. 
What is possible and also a pretty good solution is to provision temporary credentials via STS in the js layer and then pass them down to the native layer over the bridge, and either reinit a new transfer utility each time or use a credentials provider that can be updated at global scope that the transfer utility was initialized with.